# AAPT: error: style attribute 'attr/sv_animationDuration (aka com.haris.kareem:attr/sv_animationDuration)' not found

Tags: android

Could someone help me with this error? android studio

[screenshot attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xexl6.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

The sv_animationDuration attr doesn't exists in your attr file. The error message says it all.

Comment: how do I declare the attr on my attr file?